# Can a transfer switch be powered by two separate generators?

Tags: electrical, generator, transfer-switch

I have two portable generators, a Honda 2000W and a cheaper Pulsar 2000W as a backup.  They're very similar in terms of overall construction, and I wanted to see if I could combine them to power our home in an emergency where 1650 operating watts just isn't enough.  I'm not interested in powering any 30A devices, and my Honda is already successfully connected to our transfer switch via a 120V connector to a 30A F connector with the two hots jumped together, plugging into the 30A inlet on the side of the house.  There's just a question as to whether we can add more capacity to the hookup.  Enter the Pulsar.  I'm thinking of a 30A connector connecting each hot into one of two 120V male connectors that plug into either the same generator or to separate ones depending on need. I think the Reliance transfer switch is configured to run 3 breakers from each hot connection, ergo why Reliance suggests you balance the load as best as possible when selecting which 6 circuits you plan to operate.

I don't think it's necessary to sync phases on the load since each generator would connect to a separate hot line, but they would share the neutral and ground connection on the twist lock.  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4):

Connecting 2 different generators that can not be synced will cause disaster to the wiring and the smaller or cheaper generator if any 240v loads are connected. 
Using a common neutral you are taking a risk even with only 120v loads. 
With separate transfers and loads as separately derived systems could be legal but I don't think so with a common neutral.

Comment: OK.  Is this true even though they do not share a hot connection?

Comment: With them both sharing a neutral any imbalances could be injected on the other system.